# Install Packet Tracer on ARM devices

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, chrome-book, cisco

Cisco has released a packet tracer version for Android, do you know if is possible to install packet tracer on an ARM linux device (e.g. Raspberry Pi or ARM Samsung Chromebook?)

Comment: More importantly, Cisco supports packet trace for Ubuntu/Intel, "Linux Desktop Version 7.0 English / Ubuntu 14.04 supported for 64 bit; Ubuntu 12.04 supported for 32 bit"

Comment: Yep, that's great news, I've tried packettracer 7.0  in ArchLinux x86_64 and works like a charm. I would like to see it working in ARM arch Linux, though.